# What tokens to use with Popen for running a blender script?

Tags: python, subprocess, blender, popen

I have the following command which I am trying to run from python using Popen, however I am not sure what should be the tokens to be passed to it.

```
blender object.blend --background --python blenderObj.py -- box.obj object.obj
```

I tried various combinations including separately passing each of the tokens and also passing "--" and "background" together, but can't make it. Please help.

EDIT [Solution]:
as suggested by Ja8zyjits in the comments below, passing the whole command as a single string worked.

Comment: are they the command line code?

Comment: yes, that is exactly the code to be run on terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do the job for you, try this.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["blender object.blend --background --python blenderObj.py --box.obj object.obj"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: this starts blender, but it doesn't run the python script blenderObj.py which it is supposed to (specified in the arguments)

Comment: in that list [ ] pass the command line argument as a string check the spacing and also make sure that the script is run in the same file where blenderObj.py exists

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Ja8zyjits in the comments above, passing the whole command as a single string worked